# PendingIntent doesn't send Extra

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm working on an app which with you can create Screenshots of your desktop on your Android Device and while this is working fine, I've got a problem sharing the image from a notification. I'm using almost the same code for sharing from the AppBar and for sharing from the notification but the notification action isn't working. While it opens the Application Chooser how it should, it isn't sending the Image with it.

Here's the relevant code:

```
Uri lastShotUri; //populated from the MediaScanner

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, lastShotUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_share_variant_black_24dp, "Share", pendingIntent);
```

I don't get why it isn't working here but why it is working from the Application itself. If someone knows what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate help on this one.

Logcat Output (first one from ActionBar, second from Notification)

```
05-06 13:06:08.151     753-1373/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras)} from uid 10198 on display 0
05-06 13:06:15.467     753-7488/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/png flg=0xb080001 cmp=com.pushbullet.android/.ui.FloatingComposePushActivity (has clip) (has extras)} from uid 10198 on display 0
05-06 13:06:21.856     753-1706/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER flg=0x10000000 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity bnds=[216,1227][1056,1371] (has extras)} from uid 10198 on display 0
05-06 13:06:24.544      753-769/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/png flg=0xb080000 cmp=com.pushbullet.android/.ui.FloatingComposePushActivity (has extras)} from uid 10198 on display 0
```

Comment: Can you post the intent that gets printed in logcat in both cases - when it works and when it does not ? My guess is the issue is related to specifying target application.  The putExtra() part should work fine as is.

Comment: Are those the logs you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on your `shareIntent` before calling `createChooser()`.

There are some differences in the `Intent` that is being sent in both cases. In the "working" case, the flag `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` is set. This gives the target `Activity` permission to read the URI. In the logs you can also see the text "(has clip)". Read about clip data in the `Intent.createChooser()` documentation.